# Looking for an educational game from long ago, possibly called Mother Goose

Tags: secondary-education, primary-education

OK so this is really old school. Back in the 1980s, as a latchkey kid, I played on the computers in the library in elementary and middle school. There was this one bizarre educational game that I'd love to find more about.

It involved connecting a bunch of nodes with wires, creating a big rube goldberg contraption that did things to words or numbers. Press the play button and stuff pops out of some of the nodes, travels along all the little conveyer belts, interacts in some other nodes, and pops out in various places. It was a very "just play with it and see what it does" kind of game. I forget if there was even a purpose, like being required to get a certain output into a bucket or something.

"The Incredible Machine" is close but no cigar. It's not falling objects in a literal rube goldberg machine, it's squares connected by wires, like some modern day audio-processing pro software:

[image]

But this was a kiddie game. Mid-80s.

Cross-posted on Retrogaming: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/19837/looking-for-an-educational-game-from-long-ago

Comment: Perhaps ask at [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com)? Dou you remember what kind of computer it was? Thatcould have been  the glorious old days when there were no PCs nor Macs... the machine (or at least operating system) would be a required starting point, together with the year. Then again, it might have been some local development...

Comment: Later asked at [Retrocomputing Stack Exchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/19837/11421).  Whenever you cross-post to a different Stack Exchange site, please say so, so that efforts are not wasted in providing you answers that already exist.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was later asked at Retrocomputing Stack Exchange, where it has gotten an answer.

Comment: sorry, i'll edit to add that it's cross posted, i didn't realize about that. the answer is not the right answer, it has not been found.

Comment: You still don't give enough details to narrow it down. In any case, there is a better chance of success at RC.SE.

Comment: thanks, i'm looking. this has been a thorn in my brain for a decade now. not sure what prompted me to finally dig into it. the one listed below, widget workshop, is damn close to it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Was it Widget Workshop? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_Workshop

Some screenshots here: https://www.mobygames.com/game/widget-workshop-the-mad-scientists-laboratory/screenshots

You can play it in an emulator here: https://archive.org/details/widgetworkshop

Comment: wow MAYBE. this fits all the general concepts for what i was looking for. i'll have to dig a little to see if i recognize anything specific. but something very, very close to this, at least. thank you! if you know of any others that are close to this, let me know, but this is the closest i've seen yet, and very possibly it!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit like [Rocky's Boots](https://www.myabandonware.com/game/rockys-boots-cp/play-cp), a game in which you connected logic gates with wires to build machines that would kick objects with specific properties.

Comment: it's not rocky's boots.  the concept is close, but it's not logic gates per se. it some kind of other filter that passes or alters numbers or letters as they pass through, not on and off signals.